How to make tcolorbox with 3 segments?
How to make the tcolorbox with 3 segments? The below code creates 2 segments. But I need 3 segments with custom width and no margins for body of the text. Guide me to get my requirement. Thanks.
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
        \usepackage{tikz}
    
        \newtcolorbox{openningbox}[2]{
        colback = white,
        colframe = black,
        before upper = \tcbsubtitle{\tikz{\node[draw=black,fill=white,thick,rounded corners,font=\bfseries\color{black}]{Experiment #1};}},
        before lower = \tcbsubtitle{\tikz{\node[draw=black,fill=white,thick,rounded corners,font=\bfseries\color{black}]{Experiment #2};}},
        subtitle style = {
          enhanced,
          interior hidden,
          frame hidden,
          top=-0.8cm,
        },
        sidebyside,
        sidebyside align = top,
        enhanced,
        segmentation style = {solid,line width=2pt}
      }
    
      \begin{document}
    
      \begin{openningbox}{Real}{Ideal}
       \lipsum*[1]
      \tcblower
      \lipsum*[2]
    \end{openningbox}
    
    \end{document}

Result:


As far as I know, tcolorbox is designed to handle only two parts… But do you really need all the mechanism behind \tcblower?

Maybe you can just use \tcbline (but without sidebyside…) or consider raster or a standard tabular…

Agree with @NBur. Can you please add a mockup/sketch of how your tcb with 3 segments should look like? Then it may be easier to find solutions. Thank you

Hm, some general suggestions, as your intended result isn't clear enough:

a sketch of your intended result is needed here
the motivation to use tcolorbox remains unclear
I suggest to scan its manual more carefully; e.g. the example for /tcb/blanker seems to be close to what you want (perhaps ...)

Based on the latter one here's a way to obtain your 3 segments without tcolorbox. Remarks:

it simply draws a table, that's why you can only have text without linebreaks (use parbox approaches if you'd need that)
it puts it inside a Tikz-node, to obtain the rounded corner frame
arguments are limited to 3 headers and 3 text blocks
alignment and column width is one way to do it

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ how to create such a macro ~~~~~~~~~~~
%     1. code an example inside document environment
%     2. move it into a newcommand with [0] arguments AND call it
%     3. step by step introduce up to 9 arguments

\newcommand\somebox[6]{%3 x titles, 3 columns
 \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    tabl/.style={draw,rounded corners=8pt, inner sep=3mm},%
    hd/.style={ draw,rounded corners=6pt,%
                minimum width=25mm,minimum height=6mm,%
                font=\bfseries, inner sep=2mm,fill=gray!20},%
 ]%
    \node[tabl] (A){ %
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}%
        \\%
        #4 & #5 & #6\\%
    \end{tabular}%
    };%
    \node[hd] at (A.north)               {Experiment #2};%
    \node[hd] at ([xshift=-42mm]A.north) {Experiment #1};%
    \node[hd] at ([xshift=+42mm]A.north) {Experiment #3};%
 \end{tikzpicture}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

 \somebox{Real}{Middle}{Ideal}
    {\lipsum[2]}
    {\lipsum[3]}
    {\lipsum[5]}
 
 \bigskip
 
 \somebox{1}{2}{3}
    {Here came the sun.}
    {Here comes the sun.}
    {Here would have come \dots the sun.}


\end{document}


